# Difference Between A LINQ Operator and LINQ Keyword

Tags: c#, linq

In the book "Essential LINQ" by Calvert and Kulkarni, the terms "LINQ operator" and "LINQ keyword" are both used. What is the difference between these two terms?

Comment: There are no LINQ keywords...LINQ is just a series of methods in a particular namespace.  Without any further context to theorize what someone else might be referring to, we can only guess.  It would be his personal terminology though, not a generally used one.

Comment: @Servy:  Sure about that?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx

Comment: Linq Keywords;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx Linq Operators;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx

Comment: @AustinSalonen yes, as the query keywords are separate from LINQ.  That they are used with LINQ frequently doesn't make them actually a part of LINQ.

Comment: @Servy: What about this heading on the left side of that page?  _Query Keywords (LINQ)_

Comment: As the heading tells you, it is the *query* keywords, not the *LINQ* keywords.  The LINQ in parens is there as they are commonly used with LINQ, despite not actually being a part of LINQ.  The term "LINQ keywords" is really incorrect, one should use "query keywords".  Despite that term being wrong, one can still determine what it refers to anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Operators** are a set of extension methods on the IEnumerable interface providing query capabilities including : filtering, projection, aggregation, sorting. They can be applied to any enumerations and collections.

**Keywords** are a set of keywords added to the language(a language extensions) itself (C# or VB) that are used to construct a [LINQ expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx), under the hood keywords calls the corresponding operator. Not all operators have their corresponding keyword, *only some of the more frequently used standard query operators have dedicated C# and Visual Basic language keyword syntax that enables them to be called as part of a query expression*.

So, ***the difference between the two is the different form(visual impact) that they give to the code***, under the hood same methods are called(operator extension methods).

Example from msdn :

```
       string sentence = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
       // Split the string into individual words to create a collection. 
       string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');

       // Using query expression syntax. 
       var query = from word in words
                   group word.ToUpper() by word.Length into gr
                   orderby gr.Key
                   select new { Length = gr.Key, Words = gr };

       // Using method-based query syntax. 
       var query2 = words.
           GroupBy(w => w.Length, w => w.ToUpper()).
           Select(g => new { Length = g.Key, Words = g }).
           OrderBy(o => o.Length);
```

Comment: the *query* keywords (not LINQ keywords) will transform code, in a fairly rigidly defined manor, into the use of certain methods.  Those methods happen to match the signatures of various LINQ methods, but they don't actually *need* to be used in conjuction with LINQ at all.  If you define your own personal `Where` method, or `Select` method you can use the query keywords to generate calls to those methods.

Comment: @Servy feel free to edit my answer if you want to add some more informations